# Uploading files with apostrophe in filename

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I'm currently having a problem uploading files to the server that have an apostrophe in the file name. For example O'Connell.doc  The form works perfectly when there is no apostrophe in the filename.  I get a 500 Internal server error when an apostrophe is used.  It gets to form.php?p=apply Seems like the form is submitted and then immediately fails. Any ideas where to look?
Thanks!

Comment: Check if your URL is getting url_encoded properly. Use `%27` instead of `'` while uploading

Comment: @ManojAwasthi Do I need to somehow remove the apostrophe before the form is submitted?  How do I check on the url_encoded issue? Thanks

Comment: Magic quotes are enabled if that's relevant

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I have the same issue, and need to somehow remove the apostrophe before/when the file gets uploaded.

Answer (score 3):

Just jumping in here, I ran into a similar issue, it turned out that my hosting / server had "mod_security" activated, which was blocking the file by default.  I'm looking into a solution that will rewrite the file name before processing, it seems like either that or mod_security would need to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your form is vulnerable to a [Code Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) attack.  The apostrophe is being interpreted when the file is being processed and then you are getting some sort of error from that failure.

All user input needs to be sanitized to all interpreters that it will go through.  The ideal is that user input is never interpreted, only stored or called.  So rather than calling a shell on the input, use exec or something on the exact executable and arguments you want.

Comment: How do I prevent the apostrophe from being interpreted?  I tried
if(sizeof($_FILES) > 0) {


    foreach($_FILES as $k => $v) {

        $_FILES[$k] = str_replace(array("\\","'"), "", $v);

    }

}

Comment: It seems like I need to use addslashes

Comment: I am not a PHP expert, but I do know that PHP makes it very easy to add huge security holes to your application.  Keep in mind that this sort of error usually allows anyone to execute anything on your server that the "server" user can execute.

Comment: What is the line where the files are being interpreted?  What you need to do is avoid calling the shell with the filenames as arguments.